# accept button is not working in firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<input type="file" accept=".png,.jpg" />` element.
with attribute accept.

But it is accepting all the files in the firefox and safari. It is working good
in chrome and ie. How can i write code for all the browsers

Comment: The value should be a valid MIME Type.

Comment: image/png is a valid MIME type or not

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<label>Select file: 
<input type="file" name="imagefile" accept="image/jpeg, image/png">
</label>
```

More info here:
 http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/file

Comment: BTW, Mozilla guys insists in that this IS supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-accept and it DOES work in FF 23.0.1

Comment: Your answer is correct (which is nice since most of the other answers in this thread are terrible).  However, Firefox only appears to support wildcard MIME types in the `accept` attribute on file input elements, regardless of what MDN claims.  At least on OS X.  I haven't tested on Windows.

Comment: Mmm.. I tried Firefox on Windows, and it does accept multiple MIME types. However, it displays as the first option "All files (*.*)", -which I don't understand- and in the subsequent options png/jpeg, png and jpeg (in this order). I believe is a WRONG implementation decision of the Mozilla guys, but still... it's the best I can get ;)

Comment: So... is it a valid answer or not? ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for all browser

```
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: it accept all the image file not exclusive .png and .jpg. Event other files like .gif